# Compare Data on two Excel worksheets and return a shared primary key on a third worksheet

Tags: excel

I have two excel worksheets with columns A-BV and approximately 380 rows. Both sheets have the same headings, columns and rows. Column BH has the unique key for each row.

I need to find a function that will review the data on sheet 1 and compare it to the data on sheet 2. If it finds any differences I want it to highlight the cell with the difference on sheet 1 and 2 and provide the primary key on sheet three for reference.

I have not been able to figure this one out yet.

Comment: Welcome to SO! - Since you're new, I'll tell you that without showing what you've tried, you won't find much help here. The idea is for you to show us your code and attempts and we can help guide you... That being said, one way to solve this would be to use conditional formatting to highlight the differences / primary keys with differences and then filtering for color in the primary key column... Think that through (together with whatever things you're trying / thinking about) and post some code for us to try and help you with. Good luck!!

Answer (score 1):

Whereas showing some code attempt can be very helpful for VBA and such like, for a formula/ae approach I am often prepared to suggest a solution without the OP having demonstrated a failed attempt. I agree with the suggestion of applying Conditional Formatting, say in Sheet1 a formula rule such as:

```
=A1<>Sheet2!A1
```

and in Sheet2 the equivalent:

```
=A1<>Sheet1!A1
```

with each applied to `=$A:$BV`.

For the unique key I would suggest:

```
=Sheet1!A1-Sheet2!A1
```

in a separate sheet, copied down and across to suit and a formula such as:

```
=IF(SUM(A1:BV1)<>0,BH1,"")
```

copied down to suit.